# import geopandas successfully, but raise issue with fiona(import error)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, geopandas, fiona

I am Windows and using python through jupyternotebook.
python 3.9.7, windows 64 bit,
I want to import geopandas, so I used the code  `conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`. It seemed work at first because I could successfully import geopandas without error, but when I want to run the following code, an import error appears.

`world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))`

`world.columns`

ImportError: the 'read_file' function requires the 'fiona' package, but it is not installed or does not import correctly.
Importing fiona resulted in: DLL load failed while importing ogrext

I saw other people asked the same questions, but none of their solutions worked. At first, I saw someone said nstalling geopandas by condas might installed wrong version of fiona and gdal. So I tried to update by `conda update conda`, and `conda update -n base conda-package-handling` and `conda update --all`. However, these code didn't work. Later, I directly installed the .whl file from python library: **Fiona-1.8.20-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl** and **GDAL-3.4.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl**, and use pip to install them. But the error still appeared.
I really have no idea how to deal with such issue, is it because the version of fiona and gdal was not consistent? Please give me some suggestions, thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by creating a new environment followed this article: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/fastest-way-to-install-geopandas-in-jupyter-notebook-on-windows-8f734e11fa2b

This is the fast way to solve this problem.